# Adding Grids in Project Manager of QGIS

Tags: grids-graticules, layout-manager, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.12.

I am new to QGIS after having worked with ArcGIS Desktop for a while. I am having issues with adding a grid to my project.

I am using CRS ESPG:3587 WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator and noticed that the grid is showing the wrong coordinates and have included the parameters I have set for the grids.

[image: Grid settings][image: Grids showing wrong]

Answer (score 2):

In the grid properties, you would have to format the coordinates as decimal (or custom) but not as degrees

[image]