# Drawing appropriately coordinate grids

Tags: qgis, print-composer, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules

I am having an issue while trying to show the coordinates in the print layout in QGIS. While the coordinate format is in decimal and suffix, it is ok.

[image: coordinates in decimal]

I need the format in degree, minutes, and suffix. But when I had selected that option, it was showing both north and south points in the latitude, and also the east and west in the longitude.

[image: coordinates in degrees]

How to solve this problem?
There was a [relative question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359117/issue-with-grids-in-project-manager-in-qgis-3-12) like this one, but could not solve my problem.

Comment: The grid coordinates do not seem to be in degrees. Selecting the degree/minute option will basically take the given coordinate and print its modulo 360